# jQuery $.ajax - Calling error function from success function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, error-handling

In a php script, after an attempt at a database insert, I'm returning to the calling $.ajax() function either the id of the new record or an error message:

```
if ($newID > 0) {
    // Successfully added new record
    echo $newID;
} else {
    // No new record was inserted
    echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbc);
}
```

My question is: if the php else clause gets fired and I'm passing a string via the echo, then won't the success() function be called in the $.ajax function? Is there a way to somehow "fire" the $.ajax error() function depending on what's passed from the php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.ajax.error() shouldn't really be fired, as the AJAX call was a success. However, I guess you could return a different header if you really wanted to:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php and http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: I kind of thought so. If I'm getting the new ID in the php script with: "$newID = @mysqli_insert_id($dbc);" and the insert didn't work, then would the error function in the ajax call fire anyway? (I.e. do I really need the if/else code in my question?)

Comment: If the insert fails (and fails silently), the page should still return a 200, so you'll need your if/else to detect if you should return your custom header or not.